# How do I get the sidebar in Gmail to expand like old times?

Tags: gmail, user-interface

I recently switched to the redesigned version of Gmail (aka [Gmail's new look](http://gmailblog.blogspot.com/2011/11/gmails-new-look.html)) and I'm loving it.

However, one of the changes I noticed is that the bar on the left side (which has a list of all my folders and labels) automatically shrinks down to two buttons. It will only expand when I hover my mouse over it.

[image: before I hover vs. after]

This is very annoying. Is there any way I can tell Gmail to stop it?

Comment: I regarded it as a bug with the new interface design and reported it via google's feedback link.  I don't know why they had to change it - it was find before but annoying to work with flying labels in the sidebard afterward.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You should be able to grab the horizontal line (with three dots) below "Buzz". You can use that line to resize the area of the sidebar used for labels.

[image: 1]

[image: 2]

Comment: Thanks a lot. But irony of ironies: had I scrolled through the blog post I linked to I would've seen [this image](http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-7JeeLaJzPgI/Tq9pNy4TF4I/AAAAAAAAAOA/bxRa4pwj-r8/s400/control.png)!