# Expand Gmail sidebar

Tags: gmail, user-interface

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I get the sidebar in Gmail to expand like old times?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/21457/how-do-i-get-the-sidebar-in-gmail-to-expand-like-old-times)

After reading this question: [How do I get the sidebar in Gmail to expand like old times?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/21457/how-do-i-get-the-sidebar-in-gmail-to-expand-like-old-times) I tried to expand Gmail sidebar  grabbing the horizontal line below "Buzz" but I'm not able to grab her. What should I do?

Comment: Grab for the three dots under the line. (I understand you could not comment because of your rep, you can now)

Comment: No three dots here... Could be my browser or theme? (Thank you, I was afraid that my question would be considered a duplicate)

Comment: There are two icons at the bottom of that sidebar (Chat icon, and the minimize[three dots] icon). Click the three dots icon.

Comment: Thank you, I found.  The three dots just appear at the right side, maybe it's because I have Right-side chat enabled.